# Count the instances of Char in a String in a recursive function

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am trying to count the number of characters in a string coupled with a recursive function but it does not seem to be working.

```
{- characterCounts s
   PRE:  True
POST: a table that maps each character that occurs in s to the number of
     times the character occurs in s
EXAMPLES:
 -}
characterCounts :: String -> Table Char Int
characterCounts [] = Table.empty
characterCounts s = characterCountsAux s Table.empty

characterCountsAux:: String -> Table Char Int -> Table Char Int
characterCountsAux [] table = table
characterCountsAux (x:xs) table = characterCountsAux xs (Table.insert (table) x (count x (x:xs) ))


count:: Char -> String -> Int
count c s = length $ filter (==c) s
```

so in case I do: `characterCounts "atraa"` I should get `T [('a',3),('t',1),('r',1)]` but instead I get `T [('a',1),('t',1),('r',1)]`.

Suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure: is [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tables-0.4.1.1/docs/Data-Table.html) the `Table` type you are using?

Comment: I remember `Table` from a previous homework problem posted. I think it's just an association list, maybe a previous homework assignment to implement it.

Comment: newtype Table a b = T [(a,b)]

Answer (score 1):

I don't seem to have a "Table" module (in GHC).

Your code looks odd: you seem to loop over the all the chars and then try to loop again when counting (but only over the tail of the list).

There is a "count" function in the Table module linked in the other comment.

You should probably do something like

```
Table.insert table x ((count table x) + 1)
```

and remove your "count" function.

Addition: you also need to handle the first occurrence of a char in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Your Table looks a lot like a Map. So, if you can use Maps you could try the following:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

characterCounts :: [Char] -> M.Map Char Int
characterCounts = foldr ((flip $ M.insertWith (+)) 1) M.empty
```

Now, `characterCounts "atraa"` returns `fromList [('a',3),('r',1),('t',1)]`, i.e. a `Map Char Int` similar to the `Table Char Int` you are asking for. It should be easy to implement a conversion, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

When you call characterCountsAux xs _ you are giving your function the remainder of the list. That means that on the 4th iteration you are calling

```
characterCountsAux "aa" T [('a',3),('t',1),('r',1)]
```

which changes the table to T [('a',2),('t',1),('r',1)] and on the next iteration we have

```
characterCountsAux "a" T [('a',2),('t',1),('r',1)]
```

which gives you the final T[('a',1),('t',1),('r',1)].

A naive solution would be removing all occurrences of x from xs i.e.

```
characterCountsAux (x:xs) table = characterCountsAux (filter (/= x) xs) (Table.insert (table) x (count x (x:xs) ))
```

Of course it doesn't look very efficient...

Comment: Bingo! I was thinking of recursion backwardsly!